# Module angular-stripe is not available or Stripe must be available as window.Stripe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, stripe-payments

I have angular-stripe.js in my project(not sure where it came from someone else included it) an excerpt of which is below

```
var Stripe = window.Stripe

module.exports = angular.module('angular-stripe', [
  _dereq_('angular-assert-q-constructor')
])
.constant('Stripe', Stripe)
.provider('stripe', provider)
.name
```

when I include this file I get the below error

```
Error: Stripe must be available as window.Stripe
```

I downloaded angular-stripe in npm which gave me a structure like this
[image]

`src/index.js` has the same code in it as above and includes the other files in source with a `require` and when I include it I get this error

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angular-stripe' is not available!
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or know how to properly include `angular-stripe`?

**Update**
I'm including one of the following scripts in my html like this

```
<!--                <script src="assets/libs/stripe/angular-stripe.js"></script> -->
        <script src="assets/libs/stripe/index.js"></script>
```

I get the error for window.Stripe if I include angular-stripe.js and the error for the module not being available if I include index.js.  I can see one or the other in chrome developer tools when I load the page.  We are using grunt but in our gruntfile we don't include any files from `node_modules` we just use it to uglify and minify our static resources.

**Update**
When I include it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/stripe/angular-stripe.js"></script>
```

it works, but when I minifiy it I get the below error

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angular-stripe' is not available!
```

I think because it doesn't make that call to https://js.stripe.com(its not in the network data in chrome developer tools).
If I download the content of https://js.stripe.com/v2/ into a file `stripe-v2.js` and then include it like this

```
<script src="assets/libs/stripe/stripe-v2.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/stripe/angular-stripe.js"></script>
```

it works before minification but fails with the same module not available error when I try to use the minified js.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a reference to `angular-stripe`. The script either needs to be sourced in the HTML before your script is sourced.

```
<script src="scripts/angular-stripe.min.js">
<!-- source your script after this -->
```

Additionally, depending on whether you're using a build system (grunt, gulp, webpack, etc) that path would be included into the build instead, either from the `bower_components` or `node_modules` paths.

```
gulp.src([
    'node_modules/angular-stripe/angular-stripe.js'
])
```

Note that both of those are examples, the paths may differ but they have to be set to suit your environment. Without it, the `angular-stripe` script won't be loaded and your script won't work.